# What is the katakana of STAR WARS?

Tags: katakana, loanwords

スター・ワーズ?

> Sutaa Waazu?

スター・ウォーズ?

> Sutaa uoozu?

Comment: The Japanese edition of Wikipedia's article on the franchise uses [スター・ウォーズ・シリーズ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA)

Comment: Transcribing ウォー as "uoo" is a bit off. It already became pronounceable as "woo" (pretty close to _war_ in British English) in today's Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is ''スター・ウォーズ'' in Japanese. ''ウォー'' is regarded as *war* by Japanese users, but ''ワー'' doesn't make sense.